# How to specify that an attribute must be a list of (say) integers, not just a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-attrs

Using the [attrs libary](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrs) and Python 3.6, I thought the following would allow me to specify that `x` and `y` can only contain integers:

```
import attr

@attr.s
class C:
  x : List[int] = attr.ib()   # not working
  y = attr.ib(type=List[int]) # not working either
```

Both of the commented lines throw a `NameError: name 'List' is not defined`.

The reasons I expected that to work are these:

(1) The [types section of the attr documentation](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html#types) includes the following passage: "`attrs` also allows you to associate a type with an attribute using either the type argument to attr.ib() or – as of Python 3.6 – using PEP 526-annotations". It then demonstrates both methods:

```
@attr.s
class C:
    x = attr.ib(type=int)
    y: int = attr.ib()
```

(2) [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) states that the following syntax for type annotation is valid: `primes: List[int] = []`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *syntax* is indeed valid. But the generic type annotation objects added by [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) are not in the builtins namespace, but in the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module.

So, you need to do what all of the examples in the `attrs` docs you linked, and PEP 484, [PEP 483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/), PEP 526, and the `typing` docs do:

```
from typing import List
```

---

Also, note that this is just an annotation. You can still write `c = C(x=[], y=[1.0])` and you won't get a `TypeError`. As the docs you linked say:

> `attrs` itself doesn’t have any features that work on top of type metadata yet. However it’s useful for writing your own validators or serialization frameworks.

It's not at all clear what `attrs` *should* do with this metadata. It's a central part of the design of PEP 483/PEP 484 that type annotations are nothing more than annotations are runtime, and do not affect the types of values or what's legal to store where; they're only there to be used by static type checkers and other tools that runs separately from Python.

In particular, Mypy (the reference-standard static type checker), some linters, and some IDEs should flag this as an error. If they don't support `attrib` annotations yet, they're almost certainly working on it (since they're roughly equivalent to annotated attributes in [3.7/PEP 557 `dataclass`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/)).

Comment: Thanks! Now it compiles, but it's still letting me use a list of strings.

Comment: @JeffreyBenjaminBrown Yes, because static type annotations don't affect dynamic types. That's central to the design of PEP 483/PEP 484, and specifically called out in the docs you linked in a big pink box. I'll edit the answer to explain more.